# Erro ao abrir SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

É o seguinte eu tenho uma gridviewer que está conectado a um Query com uma
 Table chamada Server Table.

Eu quando quero adicionar alguma coisas ás colunas dá o seguinte erro

> Falha da instância.

Nesta parte do código

```
connection.Open();
```

Este é parte do código adiciona os valores as colnas

```
  var nothing = Resources.Nothing;
        string domain2 = Domain + "\\" + TxtBoxUpload.Text;
        if (TxtBoxUpload.Text == "" || TxtBoxUpload.Text == "Upload Name" || System.IO.Directory.Exists(domain2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Insert a valid name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Domain))
                {
                    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(domain2))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You have a project that you didnt give a name please give it a name and try again", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            System.IO.Directory.Move(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, domain2);
                            string connectionString = @"Data Source=VBSS019\\ZONESOFTSQL;Initial Catalog=ServerDown;Integrated Security=True";
                            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ServerTable(Icon, [Project Name], Directory) VALUES (@Icon, @[Project Name], @Directory)";
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Icon", nothing);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Project Name]", TxtBoxUpload.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Directory", domain2);
                            connection.Open(); //Esta é a parte do erro
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Domain);
                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.Move(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, domain2);
                        Grid.Rows.Add(new object[] { nothing, "Edit", domain2 });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Faild to move the file maybe it already exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
    }
```

Esta parte é aque mostra a gridviewer

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Data();
    }

public void Data()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=VBSS019\\ZONESOFTSQL;Initial Catalog=ServerDown;Integrated Security=True");
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT Icon, [Project Name], Directory
                                       FROM ServerTable", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            Grid.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=VBSS019\\ZONESOFTSQL;Initial Catalog=ServerDown;Integrated Security=True";
```

O prefixo `@` indica que a *string* deve ser [interpretada literalmente](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), não é necessário escapar a barra invertida `\\`, use apenas `\`.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=VBSS019\ZONESOFTSQL;Initial Catalog=ServerDown;Integrated Security=True";
```

No método `Data`, você tem a seguinte linha:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=VBSS019\\ZONESOFTSQL;Initial Catalog=ServerDown;Integrated Security=True");
```

Nessa linha escapar a barra invertida é necessário pois a *string* não tem o prefixo `@` para torná-la literal.

Comment: obrigado mas agora estou a ter o eguinte erro `ExecuteNonQuery: A propriedade Connection não foi inicializada.`

Comment: @Pedro Você definiu a conexão do `Sqlcommand`? `cmd.Connection = connection` antes de `connection.Open`.

Comment: pus agora apareçeu o seuinte erro Não existe mapeamento do tipo de objeto System.Drawing.Icon para um tipo nativo de fornecedor gerido conhecido. esta aqui o código

Comment: `System.IO.Directory.Move(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, domain2);
string connectionString = @"Data Source=VBSS019\ZONESOFTSQL;Initial Catalog=ServerDown;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ServerTable(Icon, [Project Name], Directory) VALUES (@Icon, @[Project Name], @Directory)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Icon", nothing);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Project Name]", TxtBoxUpload.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Directory", domain2);
cmd.Connection = connection;
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: @Pedro Se puder, abra uma novamente pergunta com essa dúvida, pois esse erro é diferente do erro principal da pergunta!

Comment: sim já percebi o erro é a cerca do icon eu vou tentar arranjar se não conseguir amanham abro uma nova pergunta